# Can I call non-template function over template function with same name outside class scope

Tags: c++, templates

```
/* non-template add function */
int add (int& a, int& b){
    cout << "adding"<< endl;
    return a+b;
}
/* template add function */
template <typename T>
T add(const T& a , const T& b){
    return a+b;
}
int main()
{
    cout << add(1,2) << endl;
    return false;
}
```

o/p:
3

expected :
adding
3

always template function is called. How do I call non-template function with same name outside class scope?

Comment: The non-template overload is not viable as rvalues can't bind to non-const lvalure references. Make it `int add (int a, int b){...}`, drop ampersands.

Comment: if you remove the template the non-template function is still not called

Answer (score 1):

> How do I call non-template function with same name outside **class scope**?

There is no *class scope* in your given example.

Now, you're passing **prvalues** `1` and `2` which can't be bound to non-const lvalue reference `int&`. This means the non-template function `add (int&, int&)` is not viable for the call. Thus, the template version will be used with `T` deduced to `int`.

To **solve** this you can create variables say `x` and `y` of type `int` and then pass them to `add` as shown below. This time the nontemplate version is called because `int&` can be bound to `lvalues` like `x` and `y` and the nontemplate version will be choosen over the template version.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    cout << add(x, y) << endl; //calls nontemplate version
   
}
```